# Extjs, How to remove tab panel's content

Tags: extjs

I want to destroy the tab panel's content because when I open the panel again, it remains the before contents. so it show 2 same content.

So I want to put the code to destroy tab panels content into beforeclose event handler.

and I tried like this,

```
tempTab.on('beforeclose',function(obj){
        this.items.each(function(c){this.remove(c)});
});
```

but it does not work.

Can anyone help?

source :

**ManuBar Area (MENU)**

```
menubar.add({
    text : 'Administrator',
    iconCls : 'plugin',
    menu : {
    items : [
        {
        text : 'Menu Management',
        id : 'menuManagement',
        iconCls : 'tabs',
        url : 'main/test2',
        handler : onMenuClick
        },{
        text : 'User Management',
        id : 'useManagement',
        iconCls: 'user',
        url : 'main/test',
        handler : onMenuClick
        }]
    }
})
```

**Manu Handler**

```
function onMenuClick(item) {

    if(!Ext.getCmp('tab_'+item.id)){
    var tempTab = Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanel').add({
        id : 'tab_'+item.id,
        margins : '0 5 5 0',
        deferredRender : false,
        closable : true,
        title : item.text,
        plain : true, //
        defaults : {autoScroll : true},
        autoLoad : {
        url : '/ext/main/test2/',
        scripts : true
        },
        listeners : {
        'beforeclose' : function(){
            alert(this.items.get(0).id); // output : testPanel
            this.removeAll();
                alert(this.items.get(0).id); // output : undefined
        }
        }
    });

    tempTab.on('beforeclose',function(){
        //console.log(this);
        this.removeAll(); ////////////////////////////////////
    });
    Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanel').setActiveTab(tempTab);

    }else {
    var tempTab = Ext.getCmp('tab_'+item.id);
    Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanel').setActiveTab(tempTab);
    }
}
```

**and Content(test2.php) (it load using autoLoad and scripts :true)**

```
test = function(){
return {
    init : function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    var app = new Ext.Panel({
        id : 'testPanel',
        html : 'My Second Panel'
    });

    var tab = Ext.getCmp('tab_menuManagement');
    //app.relayEvents(tab, ['activate', 'deactivate', 'beforeclose']);
    tab.add(app);
    tab.doLayout();

    tab = null; app = null;
    }
}
}();


Ext.onReady(test.init, test, true);
```

I think the item removed successfully. but still when close and open the tab again.
it show 2 same contents.

My Second Panel
My Second Panel

I don't know what is wrong....

---Updated ---

I changed the test2.php file like this

```
var tab = Ext.getCmp('tab_menuManagement');
tab.removeAll(); // I added
tab.add(app);
tab.doLayout();
```

then it works. it's weird. before close exactly it was removed. but How
it alive again....?? anybody help??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to

```
tempTab.on('beforeclose',function(obj){
     this.removeAll();
});
```

Note:

```
removeAll( [Boolean autoDestroy] ) : Array
*Removes all components from this container*.
```

Comment: I can't find where you fire beforeclose event.

Comment: tempTab.on('beforeclose',function(){
       //console.log(this);
      this.removeAll(); ////////////////////////////////////
});       <===== I hook beforeclose event.

Comment: I tried, like this, alert(this.items.get(0).id); //output : testPanel this.removeAll(); alert(this.items.get(0).id); // output : undefined. it means it removed. but when I open the tab panel again it show 2 same content. and close and open again, it show same 3 contents.... do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using some bad practices. For example:

```
variabile.on('event', handler, scope)
```

this will let `variable` alive since there is an unmanaged event (unmanaged by Ext, since it's managed by you). If you manually listen to an event, you have to uninstall it before destroy `variable`. Or if you are like me (lazy :-) just use `this.mon`.

Another bad thing is `Ext.getCmp` (and `id`) -- it should be used only for debugging purposes, not for development. When I started with Ext I used ids and I had very weird issues with TabPanel when I created multiple instances of them.